# Calling Vorto Property Values inside Model and Controller in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Till Now, I have implemented Vorto property values inside a View file (.cshtml) for a multilingual project by using...

```
@using Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Extensions
```

and then...

```
@Model.Content.GetVortoValue("propertyAlias");
```

Just wanted to know to implement or call Vorto Property Values inside a Model or Controller.

Comment: Describe your problem, what's the issue?

Comment: Please refer this link...https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/81194-calling-vorto-property-values-inside-model-and-controller-in-umbraco#comment-259545  and its final thread... you will get to know the detailed issue.

Answer (score -2):

It should just be a case of adding a reference to

```
using Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Extensions;
```

to the Model or Controller file, which will enable you to call the extension. The language that it fetches will be whatever the current thread is set to, if you wish to override it, you can call the overloaded version of the extension that allows you to pass in a language code using the "cultureName: parameter, e.g "en-GB" to get the text for a specific language. You can even specify a fallback language as well with the "fallbackCultureName" parameter.